# Cannot implement long poll

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am newbie about long poll. I want to update my wall if any new data in database by long. So as a small field I just try this below script which display `undefined` continuously in index.php page.

In I used this code in server.php `on test`, it works well.

```
while (true) {
    $random = rand(1, 10); 
    $data = ($random == 1) ? array('aaa' => time()) : array();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        flush();
        exit(0);
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Here, my problem is occurred when I was going to implement my `php query`.
I have no idea about, how to do it in my case.

How to make a query in server.php file and echo it's data at long poll?

I read about many more article about long poll, but I cannot find any good example to solved in my case.

My jQuery in index.php

```
        function fetch() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://bdshowbiz.com/server/server.php',
                async: true,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(ret, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#response').append('<p>' + ret.aaa + '</p>');
                    fetch();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    setTimeout(fetch, 5000);
                }
            });
        }
        $(function(){
            fetch();
        });
```

Current server.php file after implement query(may be it's wrong way)

```
include("../db.php");
global $dbh;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
while (true) {
    //fetch data
    $results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='1012' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    $data = $rows['description'];

    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        flush();
        exit(0);
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, using long polling with apache is a really bad idea because of the large overhead in running a persistent connection (Each request apache gets causes a process fork, with every active connection taking around 6-8mb of RAM. You are better of using something like node.js for long polling, or possibly the built in HTTP server in PHP (Im not sure how it handles connections, wether it forks or not). Or simply just do polling instead of long polling, it will result in something that is not as realtime as longpolling, but it has less overhead.

Comment: I also read more about node.js but as a newbie I cannot understand how to implement node.js. Can you give a some example for it please.

Comment: Well first of, do you know javascript? If so, then you are halfway to using node.js, as this is just a runtime for javascript. There is alot of fresh tutorials for node, it isn't that difficult to get started, with node you run your service as an app on the server, instead of putting your script file in a htdocs dir and let apache execute it on hit, that means that you cannot use node on sharedhosting, you need SSH access to your server.

Comment: Thank u sir. `There is alot of fresh tutorials for node` but I cannot found any clear step by step guide to install node.js in linux hosting server by cpanel.

Comment: Well how to depends on your linux distro, you have to use the appropriate package manager, check this out if you are in doubt: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager . I don't think that you can install it from cPanel (And I can't recommend cPanel anyways, but that is a whole other discussion)